# XSLT select // and .//

Tags: xslt, select, xpath

What are the difference between `// .//` when we set path?
And the second question if I want to get some information of parent node in the for-each block how I can get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`//` is short for descendant axis.
If you say `//para`, it selects all `para` elements in the whole document.

When you say `.//para`, all the `para` elements which are descendants of the context node are selected.

For a demonstration, consider this XML:

```
<l1>
<para>1</para>
<l2>
    <para>2</para>
    <l3>
        <para>3</para>
    </l3>
</l2>
</l1>
```

and this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/l1">
    <output>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="l2"/>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="l2">
    <para-all>
        <xsl:copy-of select="//para"/>
    </para-all>
    <para-context>
        <xsl:copy-of select=".//para"/>
    </para-context>
    <parent>
        <xsl:value-of select="name(parent::*)"/>
    </parent>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the output you will get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<output>
<para-all>
  <para>1</para>
  <para>2</para>
  <para>3</para>
</para-all>
<para-context>
  <para>2</para>
  <para>3</para>
</para-context>
<parent>l1</parent>
</output>
```

The `para-all` gets all the `para`s in the document, whereas `para-context` gets only those `para`s which are descendant of `l2`(the context node)

And about how to select the parent, as in the code(see `parent` element in XSLT).
In the example above, the context node is `l2` and by using parent axis, the parent element's name is being written.
You can use either `parent::*` or `../`

Comment: Sorry for being nit-picking. Actually, `//` is the `descendant-or-self::` axis, not the `descendant::` axis. There is no shorthand for the `descendant::` axis.

Comment: Yes, but I came across even this that `//*` is same as `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::*`, which I thought is same as `descendant::*`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If no positional predicates are involved, `//x` means the same as `/descendant::x`, and `.//x` means the same as `./descendant::x`. When positions come into play, however, you need to be aware that `//x[1]` means `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::x[1]`.